# Multiple if statements to chose particular cell in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to  write an IF statement that will chose a certain cell based on the contents on multiple other cells.

Essentially what I want to happen in cell Y2 is:

If X2 is <0 Then Y2=X2.

If X2 is >0 Then Y2=X2 BUT only if X2 < V2

If X2 is >0 AND >V2 Then Y2 = V2

What I have is the below but, it doesn't work

=IF(AND(X2<0),X2,IF(X2>0,X2,IF(X2>V2,V2)))

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if `X2=0`? `X2=V2`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IF(X2<0,X2,IF(X2<V2,X2,V2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that solve your problem:
=IF(AND(X2<>0,X2<>V2),X2,NA())

If not, then please give me some more data as to what you're trying to solve (something like a screenshot of these few cells so we understand). It's a bit hard to figure it out just with codes.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately it will not let me add pictures and this is my only post so far.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Well, does it help you what I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the minimum of X2 and V2, so simply:

```
=MIN(X2,V2)
```